# How to change the list order of ol list?

Tags: css

Use Css,not html property "reverse".
I can implement it like this:

```
<ol reversed>
    <li>test</i>
    <li>test2</li>
</ol>
```

but I want to do it by CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS to reverse

```
ol.reverse {
        list-style: none;
        counter-reset: reverse 11;
      }

      ol.reverse > li:before {
        content: counter(reverse) '.';
        display: block;
        left: -30px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        width: 20px;
      }

      ol.reverse li {
        counter-increment: reverse -1;
        position: relative;
      }
```

Your code should be

```
 <ol class="reverse">
        <li>test</i>
        <li>test2</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: In your html you have the attribute `reverse`, but you're using the class name `.reverse` in css.  So you can either use `ol[reverse]` in the CSS, or `<ol class="reverse">` in the html.

Comment: you have a typo on li closing tag and actually its not pretty clean because counter has to be set manualy

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<ol style="counter-reset: list-items 3;">
<li>test</i>
<li>test2</li>
</ol>


<style>
ol{
   list-style-type: none;
   list-style-position: inside;
 }
li:before{
   content: counter(list-items) '. ';
   counter-increment: list-items -1;
}
</style>
```